# Angularjs : make input = null when ng-hide = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello  i want to make the input text empty
when its become hidden (ng-hide="true")

i need dynamic solution work for multiple hidden inputs

so if some one checked Yes then entered child count
then if checked No  i need child count to become empty

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app>
<select ng-model="has_child">
<option value="1">Yes</option> 
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="childcount" ng-hide="has_child == 2"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="mailcount" ng-hide="has_child == 2"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="femailcount" ng-hide="has_child == 2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app>
<select ng-model="has_child" ng-change='has_child == 2 ? childcount=null: ""'>
<option value="1">Yes</option> 
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="childcount" ng-hide="has_child == 2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what if i have more than one hidden input

Comment: Use function and pass model that you need to clear to this function. For example ng-change='clearInputs(["childcount","childcount2"])'. And in controller you can clear it in cycle.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-change in your select

```
<select ng-model="has_child" ng-change="option()">
```

and add this function in your controller

```
$scope.option=function(){
    if($scope.has_child==2){
    $scope.childcount='';
    }
    console.log($scope.childcount);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks but i search for dynamic solution that work for any hidden filed in the form